# Trying to get the latest news is working but it writes all those news in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get all the latest news from the specified site in the code bellow (url), that works, I get the latest news from the site and I can successfully print those news out on screen with every one of those news in its own line.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

url = 'https://www.ljportal.com/'
headers = #my headers here
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

with open("news.txt", "a") as f:
    for i in soup.find_all("h3"):
        print(i.text)
```

But my problem is when I try to write it to a file, it gets all the news in one line and I don't know how to get them in each line. I am just replacing `print(i.text)` with `f.write(i.text)`.

Comment: Try using f.writelines(i.text) instead. Otherwise simply add a /n escape character to your

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) specifically explains that "Line separators are not added". IO types can provide a more optimised implementation, but fundamentally writelines() just calls write() in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am just replacing print(i.text) with f.write(i.text).

By default, `print` adds a line-break after whatever it prints (it also stringifies everything, and a bunch of other things). `IOBase.write` just writes whatever you give it without modifications.

You could keep using `print` and send its ouput to your file using `print(i.text, file=f)`, or you can explicitly write a newline character to your file after `i.text` (either `f.write(i.text + '\n')` or `f.write(i.text); f.write('\n')`.

Comment: Well I have now realized how stupid I am by forgetting to just write \n with each for loop... Thanks anyways.